# What is from keyword in linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Can somebody explain what `from` is used for in linq? In MySQL, `from` is used to specify the table. But I don't understand its use in linq.

```
   var artists = from a in context.Artists
                 where a.Name.StartsWith("A")
                 orderby a.Name
                 select a;
```

Comment: The from is used to specify the source of items you iterate over (ie a table). In Linq `from a in content.Artists` is pretty much the same as setting up `a` as the alias for `content.Artists`.

Comment: @Magnus u mean `a` is a table?

Comment: @AnkurSharma no `a` is the alias for the table. Like writing `from Artists As a` in SQL

Comment: @Magnus: No, it's not an alias for the table. It's a range variable.

Comment: @Jason - what's the difference in this context?

Comment: @Henk Holterman: A range variable is analogous to the iteration variable in a `foreach` statement. In neither case is the variable an alias for the data source. Note however, that in the case of the `from` clause, the range variable is merely a syntactic device; in the case of a `foreach` statement, the iteration variable actually stores instances from the data source.

Comment: @Jason Would you call it a range variable in SQL also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically means the same thing. Specifically [`from`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx) lets you specify the data source and the range variable.

That is `from a in Artists` means over the data source `Artists`, name the successive elements of the sequence `a`. For the rest of the query, `a` refers to elements of `Artists`.

The above code that you've written is equivalent to

```
var artists = context.Artists
                     .Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith("A"))
                     .OrderBy(a => a.Name);
```

If you were executing the above on a LINQ provider abstracts a SQL database, it would eventually be translated to something equivalent to

```
select * from Artists a
where a.Name is like 'A%'
order by a.Name
```

The reason it comes in a slightly different order in LINQ is to assist the parser and the IntelliSense engine.

Answer (score 3):

It is the exact same operator as in SQL.  The query statement is just written backwards to make IntelliSense and type inference work.  Those features don't work well when the FROM is at the end.

You are doing essentially the same thing when you use tooling to build a SQL statement.  You first specify what you are going to query FROM, then you draw JOIN links, then you SELECT what columns you are interested in.  A workflow that's backwards as well, just like the Linq query comprehension.  In fact, you could argue that SQL is backwards :)

Comment: SQL is not even *backwards*, it's *inside out*. The way that name resolution information "flows" in a SQL expression is bizarre, and as you point out, the order in which the computations happen is not the order in which they appear on the page. LINQ was designed to mitigate both these problems; both the scoping rules and the order of events flow pretty consistently from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

All `LINQ` query operations consist of three distinct actions:

- Obtain the data source.
- Create the query.
- Execute the query.

The `from` clause specifies the data source, the `where` clause applies the filter, and the `select` clause specifies the type of the returned elements.

So, your query is exactly similar to

```
var artists = context.Artists
                     .Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith("A"))
                     .OrderBy(a => a.Name);
```